# What should we do for queries for term definitions?

Tags: discussion

There are quite a few questions like:

- What is the definition of ...?
- What is the difference between ... and ...? (asking for definitions of the terms)

IMHO these are not DSP questions and should be flagged and closed because I consider these of very limited value and is basically the expression of "oh no, I don't know the difference and Google does not answer exactly... should I need to perform actual work by looking for individual definitions before plugging in my brain to figure out the differences or should I have someone doing it for me?".

But I am sure not everyone would agree with my view [1]. Until now, I directly asked the OPs to go and look for themselves and then to answer their own questions here.

So what do you think? Should we answer/ignore (depending on your view)? Should we flag to close? Should we encourage them to answer themselves? Anything else?

[1] Just to make things crystal clear: the little monologue is obviously ironic. I doubt that anyone asking for a comparison of available definitions would really think that deeply.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, definitions varying among sources, and differences are not obvious, or misleading. As long as the OP provides clear references, and shows he did some work understanding, I believe the request is fine.

Moreover, it can be beneficial for other users. I know about nothing about communications, and I like to read details about concepts I am not aware of.